# Prevent input type text with php variable

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

I am working with php and html,Right now i have dynamic variable and textbox i want user cant insert more than "dynamic variable value",For example if "$a=10" then in "input type text" user cant insert more than "10",How can i do this ?Here is my current code

```
<?php $a="10"; //dynamic ?>
<input type="text" name="price" value="">
```

Comment: If you want to use a number input instead then you can just use the `max` attribute. https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_max.asp

Comment: Where are you stuck? What have you've tried? [ask]

Comment: `<input type="number" name="price" min="1" max="<?php echo $a;?>">`

Comment: @bassxzero - That is bad advice as you can easily change the max value and enter a number higher than `10`...

Comment: @DarkBee .... Everything on the client side (Javascript) can be manipulated. I'm not telling him to not check the input on the backend too.

Comment: @DarkBee : please explain your point

Comment: @Jolly - What bassxzero said, never trust clientside input. Always perform serverside validation. There is a lot of reading material about this already out there about this topic.

Answer (score -1):

**Please try this code**

```js
var Numberval = '<?php echo $a; ?>';
$("#price").keyup(function(evt) {
  var self = $(this);
 
  self.val(self.val().replace(/\D/g, ""));
  
  
  if ((evt.which < 48 || evt.which > 57)) {
    evt.preventDefault();
  }

  if ( parseInt(self.val()) > parseInt(Numberval) ) {
    alert("No numbers above " + Numberval);
    self.val("");
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<?php 
$a=10;
?>
<input type='text' id='price' value="">
```

Comment: This just flat out doesn't work. You're comparing a string to a string with `>`. You need to use `parseInt()` on at least one of these inputs depending on how you solve the problem.